# yumでIPv6ネットワークを参照する不具合

Tags: centos, yum

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
を利用しています。

```
# yum update
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: ネットワークに届きません"
・・・
```

の表示でもちろんyum installもできない状況です。

IPv6を参照していることが原因かと思い、

```
vi /etc/sysctl.d/disable_ipv6.conf
```

にて

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

記載して

```
sysctl -p/etc/sysctl.d/disable_ipv6.conf
```

を実施しました。

IPv6ネットワークはdisableになりました。ip aで確認済みです。

しかし、yum updateしても同様の事象です。

/etc/yum.confを見てもproxyの設定すらしていません。
何が原因か対象方法は何かご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> echo "ip_resolve=4" >> /etc/yum.conf

こちらはいかがでしょうか。
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68586/why-yum-resolve-dl-google-com-to-an-ipv6-address

Answer (score 0):

やや対処療法ですが、`yum`が呼び出している`curl`にIPv4通信をするよう指定すると事象が改善されるかと思います。
具体的には、`${HOME}/.curlrc`に`-4`と記述します。

```
    ファイル記述例
    -4
```

＃上記指定(`curl`のオプション)は、DNSがAレコードとAAAAレコードの両方を返してくる際の挙動を制御するものです。OSのIPv6を無効化する方法でありませんので、ご留意ください。

---

訂正
`.curlrc`は`curl`コマンドに対する設定で、`yum`コマンドには影響を与えないようです。
(上記回答では解決できない)

Comment: $ more .curlrc  ->(ファイルの中身) -4
ですよね？yum updateコマンドを再度試しましたが変化ありません。
何か勘違いしているのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに~/.curlrcか/etc/curlrcに「ipv4」と記載してもyum updateでIPv6を参照してエラーになっています。

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 で外部サーバー 80番ポートに接続できないため、フォールバックして IPv6 で接続しようとして失敗しているように思います。